# Search Box in QToolbar

Tags: user-interface, qt, pyqt

Does anybody knows how to make a good search box in Qt (actualy PyQt). It should sit in the toolbar (QToolbar) and look a little different than your normal QLineEdit (rounded corners and an icon as prefix). It should be aligned right with a blank space between the rest of the controls. All tips welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To style a QLineEdit, see the official Qt Documentation. Look for "Qt Style Sheets Examples" and then "Customizing QLineEdit". For Qt 6.5, it's here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html

For the spacing, you can try adding a separator (see [QToolBar docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbar.html)) or add a left margin in the style sheet.

Comment: This is a bad answer, not only it doesn't give any code or proper explanation, but it also has broken links.